# raspberry pi 3 - preinstalled sdcard recover

Tags: recover

I have just get a new sd card preinstalled with noobs, now i am thinking where must be something wrong, because it fail with wolfram egnine and some other stuff.

Is it possible to make a recovery of something on the sd card. I don't know about filesystem and commands.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it.

I hold shift down while booting. But I tought there would be more os to choose from I only got rasbian.

Thanks.